# MATLAB plot: automatically using a column variable (Name) as Display Name in the legend

Tags: matlab, plot, label, legend

So I have a series of temperature loggers which all have a specific name and I want to plot them as follows:

[image: example of the plot]

Now, as you can see in the example plot I added, the legend automatically labels the lines as `data1, data2, data3,...`. However, I need the legend to show the names of the loggers. Because there are many loggers, I need MATLAB to do it automatically because it would take hours to use `DisplayName` and type in every logger name manually. Does anyone know how I can chose a column in my data table as the name for my lines? My table is built as follows:

```
Name of logger 1| Date | Temperature | Name of logger 2 | Date | Temperature % and so on
```

This is part of the code I use for the plots:

```
hold on
for i=2:2:35
   plot(data{:,1}, data{:,i})
end
hold off
```

structure of the

Comment: How's the table structured? The structure you present does not comply with the `plot` command you present. Can you upload the first e.g. 5 rows?

Comment: @Adriaan: I added a screenshot of the table. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DisplayName` argument of `plot`, together with dynamically retrieving the table variable names, to do this automatically.

```
vNames = data.Properties.VariableNames;
for ii = 2:2:35
    plot( data{:,1}, data{:,ii}, 'DisplayName', vNames{ii} );
end
```

Now when you call `legend`, the series will be named according to the table variable names.

---

Note that once you've got the variable names, you can equivalently index the table with them (instead of `ii` directly) like so:

```
vNames = data.Properties.VariableNames;
for ii = 2:2:35
    plot( data.Date, data.(vNames{ii}), 'DisplayName', vNames{ii} );
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't solve my problem yet, because as of now, the legend says Temp, Temp1 because it is the temperature that is plotted on the y axis. However, I want to have the name of each logger as the legend for the temperature curve. So, these names are stored in a column called name, name1, name2. If I use the syntax you posted, it just takes into account the names of the columns (i.e. name, name 1), but not actually the names of the loggers that are stored in the "name-columns". So how can I access that?

Comment: @TamaraMathys Is there a reason you can't just use `vNames{ii-1}` instead of `vNames{ii}` as the display name?

Comment: Yes, if you have a look at my table structure (I added it in the original question), I want the display name to be e.g. L-CH-01, so I want to label the temperature curves with the exact names of the loggers, not just "name" or "name1". I tried to access the first cell in the table using the following code:

plot(Chilchlinord{:,2},Chilchlinord{:,ii}, 'DisplayName', Chilchlinord.Name(1))

which should access the first cell of the column Name. But it somehow doesn't work and just displays the error message: Value must be a character vector or a string scalar.

Comment: @TamaraMathys You need to use `Chilchlinord.Name{1}` with curly braces for that to work, since `Chilchlinord.Name` is a cell array... although it's very confusing why you want to use a *row* value to correspond to the name for each *column*...